# Alter Color module fieldset within theme settings form

Tags: 7, forms

I've set up Color module for my theme - it works pretty well, but takes too much vertical space (I have a bunch of colors).
What i'm trying to do is to alter `system-theme-settings` form to make Color scheme fieldset collapsible.
So here's my code:

```
function test_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('DEBUG: ' . print_r($form['logo'], 1));
  // Above line prints array of logo settings - so function works well

  drupal_set_message('DEBUG: ' . print_r($form['color'], 1));
  /* This line prints nothing and I get:
   * 'Notice: Undefined index: color in test_form_system_theme_settings_alter()
   * (line 16 of /var/www/sites/all/themes/test/theme-settings.php).'
   */
}
```

As you can see, i can't alter $form['color'] because it doesn't exist.
Here's the [color_form_system_theme_settings_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--color--color.module/function/color_form_system_theme_settings_alter/7) function.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitly `system-theme-settings` is a core form where color module adding its fields using `hook_form_alter` in the same manner you are doing.

The point at which your `hook_form_alter` is invoked seems to be earlier then the color module's.

Check out [hook_module_implements_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) to alter the registry of modules implementing a hook.

Comment: What if you want your theme to alter the color module $form fieldset? The hook you described only lets module hooks to be re-ordered and not themes

Answer (score 2):

If you want theme to alter the color fieldset, you will need to use the `#process` variable.

For instance:

```
function YOURTHEME_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#process'][] = 'YOURTHEME_make_collapsible'
}

function YOURTHEME_make_collapsible($form) {
  $form['color']['#collapsible'] = TRUE;
  $form['color']['#collapsed'] = TRUE;

  return $form;
}
```

Functions defined in the #process variable will run after modules have done their altering. Therefore, you can access `$form['color']` and alter it from theme's theme-settings.php.

Comment: fyi this works in D8 also.